# Problemas com lentidao ao gerar um relatório jasper

Tags: java, front-end, jasper

Pessoal estou com um problema , toda vez q eu vou gerar um relatório pela primeira vez ele demora para gerar, apartir da segunda vez ele vai bem rapido , estou enviando o codigo que gera o relatorio se alguem puder ajudar agradeco

```
  public void relatorioUSALL(List lista, String tipo, Map param, String tip, String nomrel) {
    try {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();
        ServletOutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
        String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/Report/" + tipo + ".jrxml");

        //InputStream pathjrxml = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        //String path = ("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\glassfish4\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1\\applications\\Hibernate\\Report\\" + tipo + ".jrxml" );
        if (tip.equals("0")) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + nomrel + ".pdf\"");
            JasperReport pathReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(path);
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(pathReport, param,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, responseStream);
            responseStream.flush();
            responseStream.close();
            context.renderResponse();
            context.responseComplete();
        } else if (tip.equals("1")) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + nomrel + ".pdf\"");
            JasperReport pathReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(path);
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(pathReport, param,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, responseStream);
            responseStream.flush();
            responseStream.close();
            context.renderResponse();
            context.responseComplete();

        } else if (tip.equals("3")) {
            response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
            response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nomrel + ".xls");
            JasperReport pathReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(path);

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(pathReport, param,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
            ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

            JRExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, servletOutputStream);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            exporterXLS.exportReport();
            responseStream.flush();
            responseStream.close();
            context.renderResponse();
            context.responseComplete();
        } else if (tip.equals("2")) {
            response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nomrel + ".docx");
            JasperReport pathReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(path);

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(pathReport, null,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
            ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            JRDocxExporter docxExporter = new JRDocxExporter();
            docxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            docxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, servletOutputStream);
            docxExporter.exportReport();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, lendo rápido aqui seu problema, segundo o que você descreve pode ser a sua lista de Objetos, você não disse se retirou ela de um banco ou se esta pegando os itens direto do banco para o relatório através de Query, você deve estar inicializando itens desnecessários quando manda gerar seu relatório, adiciona a tag que relaciona objetos em banco o seguinte @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
faça isso para os objetos que você não usa no relatório.

Comment: Como o amigo comentou acima, o problema pode estar antes de executar essa função, uma consulta demorada ao banco de dados por exemplo, pode fazer um teste simples para chegar a algum lugar: coloca no inicio e no fim do método uma variavel para capturar o tempo que levou de execução e no final, printa o resultado no console, assim já da pra ter uma noção de se o problema é realmente dentro do método. ex: long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis(); / long fim = System.currentTimeMillis(); System.out.print(fim - inicio);, você vai ter a resposta em milisegundos.

Comment: eu fiz o teste aqui tirando a geracao do relatório, deixando somente a lista sendo populada pelo banco de dados e foi rapido, por isso acjho q o problema nao esta no banco

Comment: Felipe Souza, encontrou alguma solução? Também estou com esse problema, estou pensando em buscar os dados e trabalhar eles na aplicação, e deixando o ireport somente exibir estes dados.